# Updating an openGL VBO

Tags: c#, opengl, vbo

I am a new openGL programmer and I have gotten pretty far so far.  I program in C# so there are not a lot of examples out there and my final task to update a VBO with new data each frame.  I cannot find any examples. I'm also new to Vectors as well. So here is the basic code and what I have tried.  I am using opengl4csharp and freeglut libraries.
I initially set up a simple pyramid outside of the render callback as follows:

```
        program = new ShaderProgram(VertexShader, FragmentShader)

        // set the view and projection matrix for pyramid
        program.Use();
        program["projection_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(0.45f, (float)width / height, 0.1f, 1000f));
        program["view_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.LookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 10), Vector3.Zero, new Vector3(0, 1, 0)));


        // create a pyramid with vertices and colors
        pyramid = new VBO<Vector3>(new Vector3[] {
            new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f),        // front face
            new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),        // right face
            new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),      // back face
            new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f) });   // left face


        pyramidColor = new VBO<Vector3>(new Vector3[] {
            new Vector3(0.5f, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 0.5f),
            new Vector3(0.5f, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 0.5f), new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0),
            new Vector3(0.5f, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 0.5f),
            new Vector3(0.5f, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 0.5f), new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0) });


        pyramidTriangles = new VBO<int>(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 }, BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer);
```

I then execute the following in OnRender callback:

```
        // use our vertex shader program
        Gl.UseProgram(program);

        // bind the vertex positions, colors and elements of the pyramid
        program["model_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.CreateRotationY(yangle) * Matrix4.CreateRotationX(xangle));              
        Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(pyramid, program, "vertexPosition");
        Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(pyramidColor, program, "vertexColor");
        Gl.BindBuffer(pyramidTriangles);
        Gl.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, pyramidTriangles.Count, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero);
```

This works great I then have a nice pyramid display.  Now in the real application it will have a lot more than the single pyramid and this will be updated in real time.  This is where I have my issue.  I do not understand how to update the VBO properly.  This is what I have tried in the OnRender callback.  This is just an example with the very first vertex changed

```
        Gl.UseProgram(program);

        pyramid = new VBO<Vector3>(new Vector3[] {
            new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f),        // front face
            new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),        // right face
            new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),      // back face
            new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f) });   // left face


        // bind the vertex positions, colors and elements of the pyramid
        program["model_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.CreateRotationY(yangle) * Matrix4.CreateRotationX(xangle));              
        Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(pyramid, program, "vertexPosition");
        Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(pyramidColor, program, "vertexColor");
        Gl.BindBuffer(pyramidTriangles);
        Gl.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, pyramidTriangles.Count, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero);
```

This also works however I when I exit the program I get a System Access Violation Exception.  This is the same error one gets if they do not dispose of one of the vertex objects.  However in this case I do call dispose.  Does this mean I need to call dispose each time I use this?
I aslo heard something about glMapBuffers but can find no examples.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you add a link to the library you use? And also could you include the lines, where you call glBufferData()?

Comment: Hi sorry the name of the library was incorrect.  It is opengl4csharp. Here is the link https://github.com/giawa/opengl4csharp.  As to the glBufferData that is done in the Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created new VBO objects, instead of updating the existing one. So the VBOs are piling up on the video card.

When the documentation of a library is bad, then it's a good idea to look into its source code. That library consists mainly of 3 parts:

1. Low level OpenGL bindings: https://github.com/giawa/opengl4csharp/blob/master/OpenGL/Core/GlCore.cs

   The code there just call functions from an OpenGL dll.
2. Higher level functions. For example you mentioned in a comment, that you upload the buffers to the GPU using the BindBufferToShaderAttribute function: https://github.com/giawa/opengl4csharp/blob/master/OpenGL/Core/GlMethods.cs#L600

   As you see that function just calls some lower level OpenGL functions. Also notice that it doesn't upload the buffers to the GPU, so that happens somewhere else. (It just marks entries in the buffer for passing them as attributes to the shaders.)
3. High level classes. For example the VBO class you used in your example: https://github.com/giawa/opengl4csharp/blob/master/OpenGL/Constructs/VBO.cs

   Notice that its constructor calls CreateVBO: https://github.com/giawa/opengl4csharp/blob/master/OpenGL/Constructs/VBO.cs#L54

   And that CreateVBO method has a call to glBufferData, which I mentioned in my comment: https://github.com/giawa/opengl4csharp/blob/master/OpenGL/Core/GlMethods.cs#L342

So it is the VBO class, which uploads the buffer to the GPU. We can expect that you can modify the buffers with the same class. And there it is: https://github.com/giawa/opengl4csharp/blob/master/OpenGL/Constructs/VBO.cs#L129

The BufferSubData method of the VBO object can be used for modifying the buffers. Example:

```
Vector3[] vertexBuffer = new Vector3[] {
    new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f),       // front face
    new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),       // right face
    new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),     // back face
    new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f) };   // left face

pyramid.BufferSubData(vertexBuffer);
```

Comment: Excellent! You can tell I'm not an expert. Now the next question is how does one update this is a loop?  For example, this will change alot and the real object will be much larger.  I don't understand how I could access these vectors in a loop.  For example an array gets created as array[] _array = new array[x] and then you can access an element as _array[x] = 123; But how do you do this with this object? Many thanks!

Comment: So you want to change the vertices of the pyramid during the render? What sort of change is that? Can that be implemented with affine transformations? (Example: stretch, rotate, translate, skew)

Comment: Yes, the transformations are fine. The actual app will be updating a 3d grid in real-time so I need to update the vertices and I don't know how in the object.

Comment: @Tom: If you want to transform only a single object and nothing else, then first make sure that `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)` is called (you call this usually after the init of OpenGL is complete, and the perspective is set). Then save the current matrix by calling `glPushMatrix()` (because we will restore it later). Then apply the transformation you want, and draw the buffers. Then restore the original matrix with a `glPopMatrix()`. So you don't need to change the content of the buffers if you only do affine transformations.

Comment: @Kitten I understand that part. Where I am hung up, is how to update this pyramid.BufferSubData object.  I will have a loop, and I will be updating all of the vertices in real-time, changing each vectors x,y, and z values.  I cannot figure out how to update all the vectors in a loop without writing the pyramid.BufferSubData explicitly as in the above.  I will have a total of 200,000 vectors to update.

Comment: The pyramid is just an example. It is not the real data.

Comment: Ah I think this question is more about C# than OpenGL? Hmm it's not a good idea to recreate a Vector3[] array for each frame, because then the garbage collector would cause lags randomly. Create it only once, and for each frame iterate through it, and modify its values, then pass it again to `BufferSubData()`.

Comment: Exactly!  This is now a pure C# question.  How do I iterate through it? I know how for an array[] but this?

Comment: :) It's just a normal C# array (although its elements are from the opengl4csharp library, but that doesn't matter). You can add new elements to it by https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310854.aspx , and you can iterate through it by: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3zzhdw.aspx  Just instead of `int i` you will have `Vector3 v`.

Comment: I've updated my answer: separated the array from the BufferSubData call. Is it clear now?

Comment: Nope, I guess I'm just dense lol.  So in the latest example, how does one create the vertexBuffer you created in a loop instead of always writing new Vector3(0,0,0), etc?  And then once you have done this the first time, how do you update all the vertices? Sorry if this is such a newbie question.

Comment: Ok.  I do Vector3[]  vertexBuffer = new Vector3[1000] for example.  This works.  Then it's vertexBuffer[100].X = 1, etc.  Ok.  Finally I got it!!  It's hard enough learning openGL but then my lack of extensive C# experience also gets in the way lol.  So much thanks for this!  I worked on all of this for 2 days!

Comment: Ah no :) the `new Vector3[1000]` already created 1000 empty vectors. So you can do `vertexBuffer[1].x = 1; vertexBuffer[1].y = 1; vertexBuffer[1].z = 1`.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, now I got it!!!  Still a newbie in C# and I think I always will be even though I've written 10s of 1000s of line of code lol....Very much appreciated!